# Drawing a circle with GDI graphics on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, drawing, gdi

I need to draw with GDI graphics a circle on my form in WPF.
I can't do this with windows forms, so i have added a using.
I can not use the Elipse controls from WPF. My teacher told me to do this like this.

This is my code:

```
public void MakeLogo()
{
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
    myBrush.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

And this is the error:

> MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'CreateGraphics' and no extension method 'CreateGraphics' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "I need to draw with GDI graphics a circle on my form in WPF". For what reason? Why can't you use a WPF Ellipse control?

Comment: It's one of the requirements of my assignment. I dont know why my teacher wants this. @Clemens

Comment: I'm guessing you misunderstood this assignment and you are supposed to do this in WinForms.

Comment: Nop. I have to do it in WPF @LarsTech

Comment: He said: "Make with GDI Graphics a new logo in WPF."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use GDI within WPF directly, to achieve what you need, please use [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx). Add references to System.Windows.Forms and WindowsFormsIntegration, add it to xaml like this (should have something inside, like Panel or whatever):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <!--whatever goes here-->
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="someWindowsForm">
            <wf:Panel></wf:Panel>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <!--whatever goes here-->
    </Window>
```

Then your code-behind will look like this and you'll be ok

```
    SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
    Graphics formGraphics = this.someWindowsForm.Child.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300)); 
    myBrush.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
```

UPD: good idea to make use of `using` statement here:

```
using (var myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green))
            {
                using (var formGraphics = this.someForm.Child.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
                }
            }
```