# Hot to draw Arc in WPF application similar to GDI - Arc() method?

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi

I am currently porting a C++ application to WPF. The C++ application uses GDI for Graphics drawing. 
For drawing an Arc , in C++ application the following GDI API is used .

```
WINAPI Arc( __in HDC hdc, __in int x1, __in int y1, __in int x2, __in int y2, __in int x3, __in int y3, __in int x4, __in int y4);
```

I need to convert this to WPF Arc. Please help

I have already tried drawing Arc segment in WPF. But the output doesnt match with the GDI drawing.

```
    private void DrawArcSegment(double strokeThickness, SolidColorBrush colorBrush, 
        double left, double top, double right, double bottom,
        double startArcX, double startArcY, double endArcX, double endArcY)
    {
        System.Windows.Shapes.Path arc = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
        PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
        PathSegmentCollection segments = new PathSegmentCollection();

        Point center = new Point(left + ((right - left) / 2), top + ((bottom - top) / 2));
        double degrees = Math.Atan2(startArcY - center.Y, startArcX - center.X)
                        - Math.Atan2(endArcY - center.Y, endArcX - center.X);

        degrees *= 57.2957795; // Convert from radians to degrees
        bool isLargeArc = Math.Abs(degrees) > 180;

        arc.Data = new PathGeometry();

        figure.StartPoint = new Point((startArcX), (startArcY));

        ArcSegment segment = new ArcSegment
        {
            Point = new Point(endArcX, endArcY),
            Size = new Size((right - left) / 2, (bottom - top) / 2),
            RotationAngle = 0,
            IsLargeArc = isLargeArc,
            SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise
        };

        segments.Add(segment);

        figure.Segments = segments;
        arc.Stroke = colorBrush;
        arc.StrokeThickness = strokeThickness;
        ((PathGeometry)arc.Data).Figures.Add(figure);

        drawingCanvas.Children.Add(arc);
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you when you don't explain your problem. While we might try to find the documentation if the GDI Arc method, and then try to imagine how you used it, it would be far better if you explained what you are trying to achieve. As a hint, the Size property of the ArcSegment specifies the radii in x and y direction of the elliptical arc segment.

Comment: Here's a discussion about GDI and WPF, which you can refer to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621506/drawing-a-circle-with-gdi-graphics-on-wpf